# Appium _org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, android, appium

[image: image of my project structure and apk location]

I am running appium script , for android app.

But it is not at all running.

I have added all the dependency in my maven project required to run the test.

Adding all of my code below.

Please check and help me.

Launch Class

```
      package TestCases.Project_Entry;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

    public class launch {

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

        public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File appDir = new File("src");
            File app = new File(appDir, "app-staging-debug.apk");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Palak");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "25");
            capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);

            capabilities.setCapability("--session-override", true);
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            return driver;
        }

    }
```

1. I have already tried , re-starting eclipse.
2. Adding automation name as ui automator 2

```
    package TestCases.Project_Entry;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;

    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;

    import PageObject.loginObjects;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

        public class loginTestCases extends launch {
            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

            @BeforeTest
        public void openapp() throws MalformedURLException {
            capabilities();
        }



        @Test
        public void log() {


            driver.findElementById("versionx.entryPoint:id/ed_verificationEmail").sendKeys("213214");

        }

    }
```

Error Showing:-

```
>[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest openapp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original 


>===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================



>===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: What does the Appium server log say?

Comment: thub.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
[debug] [W3C]     at ADB.apkUtilsMethods.startApp (C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:137:11)
[debug] [W3C]     at <anonymous>
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 54840 ms - 1529
[HTTP]

Comment: Please check if my apk path is correct , i have a doubt with that.

Comment: Please check image attached.

Comment: My Appium logs are saying incorrect package and activity name, But i have used apk path to find app, than why it is asking for package and activity?

[debug] [ADB] Found package: 'versionx.entryPoint' and fully qualified activity name : 'versionx.entryPoint.Activity.VerificationActivity' [debug] [ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.

Comment: As far as I know you always need to set package and activity name. It is needed to start the installed app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a capability.

`capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "*");`

Also re-check APK path

Comment: appWaitActivity tells appium which activity to wait to open when app launches. * means any activity. NewCommandTimeout means appium command time out. http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Comment: Can you tell me how should we apply aapWaitActivity in our code.

Comment: Is it like this:-

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity","versionx.entryPoint.Activity.SplashScreenActivity");

Comment: I have kept wait activity in my code, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please check my code below  and let me if it looks fine:-

Comment: code is not getting added in comments because it is too long.Please let me after which capability this wait one should come. May be because order of capability i am setting , this issue is happening

Comment: try capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity","*");

Comment: Yes , i did that also

Comment: But same error. When we use absolute path method to find out apk,that time we don't need to put package and activity name .Right?

Comment: you always need activity name

Comment: You always need both path to the apk file and the activity name.

Comment: Check from appium logs which activity it tries to launch to see that if it's the right one. Sometimes it might miss the splashscreen. So that's  why I used(*)

Answer (score 0):

just to discard the possibility, place your app on desktop and add the path from there, it will be hardcoded, but its just to make sure that the app path is not the problem.